# Writing to configfs sysfs from C++ fails but works if done with bash commands

Tags: c++, sysfs

An small update: I was able to write to my sysfs path with `freopen` :)

Trying to play around with my phone's usb gadget, and enable myself to use my phone to serve an ISO to my PC, I've noticed something very weird.

With the code bellow, I'm trying to write the usb controller name to `/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC` but I always run into `Device or resource busy` while doing `echo` from the cmdline works perfectly fine. Any way to fix this without using `system()` ?

```
void sysfs_write(char *path, char *content)
{
    std::cout << "Write: " << content << " -> " << path << std::endl;
    int fd = open(path, O_WRONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Failed");
        return;
    }
    int n = write(fd, content, strlen(content));
    if (n == -1)
    {
        perror("Failed");
    }
    close(fd);
}


sysfs_write("/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC", "");
sysfs_write("/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC" , "a600000.dwc3");
// Both fail with Device or resource busy
```

- stat

```
  File: /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 0,17    Inode: 249229      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-02-01 01:17:16.229999999 +0200
Modify: 2023-02-01 01:28:46.424746782 +0200
Change: 2023-02-01 01:28:46.424746782 +0200
 Birth: -
```

```
  File: /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 0,17    Inode: 18684       Links: 4
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-02-01 01:18:00.646458114 +0200
Modify: 2023-02-01 01:17:23.679999997 +0200
Change: 2023-02-01 01:17:23.679999997 +0200
 Birth: -
```

Comment: On what line do you get "Device or resource busy"?

Comment: On `int n = write(fd, content, strlen(content));`. But I've found something. Looking how tee does this, I've found about `freopen` which works fine. Wondering if there's a better way than doing `freopen` now

Comment: Try `open(path, O_WRONLY | O_DIRECT);`

Comment: @273K well thanks for trying to help, in the end seems that was just my confusion (see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75304509/18338105). Thanks again for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so RIP me. I had it from the first try, but my code was broken somewhere else, since I'm building the path I'm giving to the function, and after I fixed that I just assumed I already tried this but I guess not.

```
void sysfs_write(char *path, char *content)
{
    std::cout << "Write: " << content << " -> " << path << std::endl;
    std::ofstream sysfsFile(path);
    sysfsFile << content << std::endl;
    sysfsFile.close();
}
```